# subprocess.Popen for "ssh sudo -u user -i" is failing with "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, tty

I want to ssh into a remote server, change user then execute a script. I'm using `subprocess` to do this but it appears `sudo -u userB -i` is not changing user.

```
HOST = 'remote_server'
USER = 'userA'
CMD = ' whoami; sudo -u userB -i; whoami'

ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '{}@{}'.format(USER, HOST),CMD],
                            shell=False,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()   
if not result:
    err = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(err))
else:
    print "success"
    print(result) 

$ success
$ ['userA\n', 'userA\n']
```

When I replaced with `CMD ='sudo -u userB -i && whoami'`, I got this error:

> ERROR: ['sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\n']

On the terminal, I'm able to do passwordless ssh, `sudo -u userB -i && whoami`

Answer (score 5):

`sudo` on the target system is configured to require a [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). That is usually done to actually *prevent* the kind of automation you are trying to implement. Talk to your server administrator, before trying to bypass that restriction. Either the restriction is not needed, then the admin can turn it off for you. Or there is a reason for the restriction and the Administrator won't be happy that you are trying to bypass it.

The restriction can be turned off by removing `requiretty` option from [`sudoers` file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) (the option is off by default).

---

To make `ssh` use the terminal emulation for the command provided on its command-line, you need to use [`-t` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t). But for `-t` to actually have any effect, you need to run `ssh` from a terminal in the first place. As `subprocess.Popen` is not a terminal, you will get:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

To bypass that, you have to use double `-t` switch: `-tt`.

Comment: For linux admins: requiretty as a default is not a good idea:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147

Answer (score 0):

Inserting this line in `/etc/sudoers` on the remote server will resolve the issue:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem with a small C program and give it the suid permission, i.e.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    setuid(0);//su
    char *cmd="/usr/sbin/hddtemp";
    char *arg[]={(char *)"hddtemp",(char *)"--numeric"};
    #define array_size(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x))
    int size=array_size(arg);
    size_t i,n=size+argc;
    char **args=malloc((n)*sizeof(char*));
    if(args==NULL)return 255;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        args[i]=malloc(strlen(arg[i])+1);
        if(args[i]==NULL)return 255;
        strcpy(args[i],arg[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++){
        args[size+i]=malloc(strlen(argv[i+1])+1);
        if(args[size+i]==NULL)return 255;
        strcpy(args[size+i],argv[i+1]);
    }
    // printf ("total args %2zu\n",i);
    // for(i=0;i<n;i++)printf ("args[%2zu] : %s\n",i,args[i]);
    execv(cmd,args);
    return 1;
}
```

First, compile with:

```
gcc -Wall program.c -o program
```

Then, chown and chmod to

```
chown 0:userB program
chmod 4750 program
```

And, if you don't have the need to mix hardcoded arguments with passed ones you could just use the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    setuid(1000); //user id of userB
    char *cmd="/usr/bin/whoami";
    execv(cmd,argv);
    return 1; // indicate error if execv() didn't succeed.
}
```

In general, every admin will advise you against adding exceptions to **/etc/suders** and there's a good reason why.